# Select 1 table, update another

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update users within a table, that have rank 3 in another table. Here's an example:

t1:

```
id   respect   activity_points
1    10        1200
2    10        700
3    10        90
```

t2:

```
id   rank
1    3
2    1
3    1
```

---

I'm trying to update 'respect' in table1 where rank is equal to 2 or above, from table2.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for the SQL answer not PHP and assuming that t2.id is id that maps to the id in t1

```
update t1 
inner join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
set t1.respect = (t1.respect + 5) 
where t2.rank >= 2
```

Comment: By MSSQL you probably mean `SQL`? (Because OP tagged question by mysql)

Answer (score 0):

```
Query : update t1 set respect=newvalue where id 
        in ( select id from t2 where rank > 2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE t1 SET respect = 'your value' WHERE id in (
    SELECT id FROM t2 WHERE rank >= 2
)
```

or

```
UPDATE t1 SET respect = 'your value' WHERE id = (
    SELECT id FROM t2 WHERE rank >= 2
)
```